# One or more errors occurred during processing of command. Provider error '80040e14'

Tags: asp-classic, ldap

I am getting a Provider error '80040e14' when I do a LIKE on an LDAP query in Classic ASP.

My code is:

```
<% 
response.Buffer = True

function get_ldap_query(firstname, lastname, unit)
    dim ADUser, objCom, objCon, objRS
    ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
    ' Make AD connection and run query'
    Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
    objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\test"
    objCon.Properties("Password") = "example"
    objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
    objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
    objCom.CommandText = "SELECT givenName, sn, mail, telephonenumber, mobile, description, sAMAccountName, cn, UserAccountControl FROM '"+ ADUser + "' where (cn LIKE *" + firstname + "* OR cn like *" + lastname + "*) AND UserAccountControl <> 514 ORDER by cn ASC" 
    Set objRS = objCom.Execute
    Response.Write "<table>" + vbCrLf
    Do While Not objRS.EOF Or objRS.BOF
        Response.Write "  <tr>"
        Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("givenName") + "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("sn") + "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("mail") + "</td>"
        ' Check if field is null to avoid error'
        If IsNull(objRS.Fields("Description").Value) Then
            sDesc = ""
        else
            For Each item In objRS.Fields("description").Value
                sDesc = item + "<br>"
            Next
        end if
        Response.Write "<td>" + sDesc + "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("mobile") + "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" + objRS("telephonenumber") + "</td>"
        if objRS("sAMAccountName") <> mid(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"), 11) then
            'If the account name held in AD is different to the one the user is logged in with, a blank cell is output. If they are the same, a link allowing the user to edit their entry is displayed'
            Response.Write "<td></td>"
        else
            Response.Write "<td><a href='entry.asp?account_name=" + objRS("sAMAccountName") + "'>Edit</a></td>"
        end if
        Response.Write "</tr>" + vbCrL
        objRS.MoveNext
        Response.Flush
    Loop
    Response.Write "</table>"
    'Clean up'
    objRS.Close
    objCon.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    Set objCon = Nothing
    Set objCom = Nothin
end function
%>
```

When this function is called from the index.asp page, which passes the data to the function, I get the error:

> Provider error '80040e14'
>
> One or more errors occurred during processing of command.
>
> /pagelets/includes/results.asp, line 19

Which is

```
Set objRS = objCom.Execute
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In ASP to concatenate strings, you use ampersands (`&`) not plus signs (`+`)

Comment: Actually @JenR you can use both, although I'd stick to `&` over `+` it just confuses things.

Comment: @Lankymart Good to know - somehow I have never run into that actually working before. I could swear it has actually caused an issue for me, but it's a vague enough memory that I just remember "don't use + for concatenation"

Comment: Which line is line 19?

Comment: Line 19 is the    Set objRS = objCom.Execute
 line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below line

```
objCom.CommandText = "SELECT givenName, sn, mail, telephonenumber, mobile, description, sAMAccountName, cn, UserAccountControl FROM '"+ ADUser + "' where (cn LIKE *" + firstname + "* OR cn like *" + lastname + "*) AND UserAccountControl <> 514 ORDER by cn ASC"
```

You are missing single quotes around the firstname and last name, it should look like below.

```
objCom.CommandText = "SELECT givenName, sn, mail, telephonenumber, mobile, description, sAMAccountName, cn, UserAccountControl FROM '"+ ADUser + "' where (cn LIKE '*" + firstname + "*' OR cn like '*" + lastname + "*') AND UserAccountControl <> 514 ORDER by cn ASC"
```

Your code sample also does not show how these are being set, so they could be empty, in which case you get ALL records, in which case you might be returning too many records.  You need to add some logic to check if both are these are empty and exit gracefully, or limit the number of records returned somehow.